# Add a class to an element when another element is clicked

Tags: javascript, popup

I am trying to add a class to an element when another element is clicked upon.

This is for a popup script and I'm trying to do it by toggling the CSS opacity property.

This is my HTML,

```
<span class="container">
  <span class="visible-text" onclick="addClassToPopUp()">
  </span>
  <span class="popup-text">
  </span>
</span>
```

And it repeats multiple times.

The visible text on the page is contained within the `.visible-text` class and the popup text is within the `.popup-text`. The opacity of the `.popup-text` class is zero.

I want to add a class to `.popup-text` when the `.visible-text` box is clicked. The class would overwrite the opacity to 1.

Now my question,

I can get a list of all classes using `document.getElementsByClassName("popup-text");` but how do I narrow it down the current one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to limit it to the parent element

```js
function addClassToPopUp(elem) {
   var popUp = elem.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("popup-text")[0]; 
   popUp.classList.toggle("active");  
}
```

```css
.popup-text {
   display:none;  
}

.popup-text.active {
   display:block;  
}
```

```html
<span class="container">
  <span class="visible-text" onclick="addClassToPopUp(this)">Hello
  </span>
  <span class="popup-text">World
  </span>
</span>
```